# How to setup a micro service to run in any available port with in a particular range in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices

I am trying to implement a microservice in SpringBoot that will have several instances running on the same virtual server for load balancing. Rather than assigning a specific port at deployment time, I want to configure the microservice to dynamically use an unused port from a preconfigured  range of ports.

I have not yet tried anything to solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

SocketUtils has been removed in Spring Boot 6. It was never intended for use on production, only for integration tests. Spring docu discourage to read available ports. For random port setting server.port=0 is the correct way. Letting server to provide one for you.